# Cancancan ability for guest user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancancan

Site is having model Post which just display a Post, nothing fancy
If in Ability i add
When no user is logged it they should be able to read all the post
So in Ability.rb

```
def initialize(user)    
        can :manage, Post
end
```

This works but of course it should be

```
def initialize(user)    
        can :read, Post
end
```

Which doesn't work  (403)

Based on what I've read :read should alias for index show actions
I can't find a way to debug why it fails.
All help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are automatically authorizing all actions in a RESTful style resource controller with `load_and_authorize_resource` method. If the `index` action does not require user to login then you should skip this method specifically for `index`. Try

`load_and_authorize_resource :except => [:index]`